# AdBlock for Chrome Blacklist not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, adblock

Since a few days ago, my [AdBlock for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) stopped blocking ads in my Blacklist:

```
sourceforge.net##A[id="sf_logo"][href="https://sourceforge.net"]
sourceforge.net##IMG[src="./styles/sf/imageset/site_logo.gif"]
sourceforge.net##IMG[src="./download/file.php?avatar=104_1285881680.jpg"]
sourceforge.net##IMG[src="./download/file.php?avatar=68_1285700750.jpg"]
sourceforge.net##IMG[src="./download/file.php?avatar=70_1285721087.jpg"]
sourceforge.net##IMG[src="./download/file.php?avatar=98_1285765712.jpg"]
sourceforge.net##IMG[src="./download/file.php?avatar=133_1285958867.jpg"]
sourceforge.net##IMG[src="./download/file.php?avatar=138_1286139142.jpg"]
sourceforge.net##IMG[src="./download/file.php?avatar=93_1285946635.jpg"]
sourceforge.net##IMG[src="./download/file.php?avatar=127_1286243352.jpg"]
sourceforge.net##IMG[src="./download/file.php?avatar=96_1285797673.png"]
```

I checked to see if it was only that site, and tried blocking Google's logo. It didn't work, either. I even reinstalled [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) + [Browser Button For AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/picdndbpdnapajibahnnogkjofaeooof), but the problem remained.

All the normal ads (Filter List) are blocked, of course. I've subscribed to "AdBlock custom filters", "EasyList", "Easy Privacy", and "Malware Domains".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a bug since I have the same problem (I've noted it about week ago). I've just found this question buy googling it. Probably it's a good idea to [report an issue](http://code.google.com/p/adblockforchrome/issues/entry).

In order to check, if I can list the steps for reproducing the problem I've installed AdBlock to another computer and successfully locked google's logo. My configuration:
1. Chrome 7.0.517.41, Windows XP x32, AdBlock 2.2.7, personal filter is not working.
2. Chrome 7.0.517.41, Windows 7 x64, AdBlock 2.2.7, personal filter is working.

So if you will be able to find the desired list of steps, please, [report it](http://code.google.com/p/adblockforchrome/issues/entry).

Comment: Here it is: http://code.google.com/p/adblockforchrome/issues/detail?id=4771

Answer (score 1):

Please update your filters

Famlam (AdBlockforChrome)

Comment: Already did that yesterday... It works now, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. The Chrome extension seems to add user blacklist entries wrong, the syntax seems to be incorrect. When I blocked the ad using firefox then copied the filter I'd created over it started blocking the ad just fine. Not sure whats causing this.

Basically if you want to block and ad in Chrome you have to block it in Firefox first, unless you know the syntax for blacklisting ads manually.

Comment: Ummm... This question's resolved.